# Count in a progressive manner in Excel

Tags: excel, function

I have the following set of data in excel:

```
11  AGRICULTURE
11  AGRICULTURE
11  AGRICULTURE
321 FOREST NURSERIES AND GATHERING OF FOREST PRODUCTS
411 FISHING
551 METAL SERVICE CENTERS AND OTHER METAL MERCHANT WHO
551 METAL SERVICE CENTERS AND OTHER METAL MERCHANT WHO
321 FOREST NURSERIES AND GATHERING OF FOREST PRODUCTS
551 METAL SERVICE CENTERS AND OTHER METAL MERCHANT WHO
```

And I want to count in a progressive way when a character reappears. With a countif function it only shows the total of the occurrences. Is there any way for my data to appear as follows?

```
1   11  AGRICULTURE
2   11  AGRICULTURE
3   11  AGRICULTURE
1   321 FOREST NURSERIES AND GATHERING OF FOREST PRODUCTS
1   411 FISHING
1   551 METAL SERVICE CENTERS AND OTHER METAL MERCHANT WHO
2   551 METAL SERVICE CENTERS AND OTHER METAL MERCHANT WHO
2   321 FOREST NURSERIES AND GATHERING OF FOREST PRODUCTS
3   551 METAL SERVICE CENTERS AND OTHER METAL MERCHANT WHO
```

Obviously I could do this manually as I just did with the above data but I have a much bigger data set in my computer.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this COUNTIF():

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,B1)
```

Pay attention to what is and what is not an absolute reference.

So as it is dragged down it will change on its own to reference an ever larger range.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: Only if your data is sorted. (Thanks @Scott-Craner for pointing out the assumption)

Using only `IF` formula:

Enter cell A1 `=1` (the number 1)

In A2 `=IF(B2=B1,A1+1,1)`

(Other answers are correct too, just listing this as another method)

[image]

Comment: You are not getting the correct output.  Yours works if the data is sorted, but his data is not sorted.  For example row 20 should be 2 not 1

Comment: Ah yes, didn't realise the counter had to go up even in the later ones. Taking this answer off in 1min (so that you can see my comment). Thanks for that.

Comment: You can leave it just put the instructions that it needs to be sorted

Comment: The OP may prefer it, who knows.

Comment: Thanks, will leave it. (Am too new to SO, and too old for the internet probably :P, what does OP stand for?)

Comment: OP --> Original Poster or Original Post.  They are used interchangeably depending on context.  And you are probably not older than myself.  I was alive when vinyl was not retro.